# JSONEncoder works for [String:String] fails for [String:Codable]

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I'm playing around with the new `Codable` protocol and `JSONEncoder`

The following method throws an odd exception:

```
  private func generateJSONData(body: [String: Codable]?) -> Data? {
    guard let body = body else {
      print("empty body for json encoding")
      return nil
    }

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
     let data = try encoder.encode(body)
      return data
    } catch {
      print("error encoding body to json")
      return nil
    }
  }
```

`fatal error: Dictionary<String, Decodable & Encodable> does not conform to Encodable because Decodable & Encodable does not conform to Encodable.`

This even gets funnier when I change the signature to

`private func generateJSONData(body: [String: Encodable]?)`

`fatal error: Dictionary<String, Encodable> does not conform to Encodable because Encodable does not conform to Encodable.:`

The interesting thing is that this works fine with `[String: String]`

Is there a reason `[String: Codable]` is not codable?

Comment: Its because protocols don't conform to themselves.See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/)

Comment: And the solution, as I demonstrate [in my answer to the linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878), is to create a type-erased wrapper `AnyEncodable` that conforms to `Encodable` and forwards calls to `encode(to:)` to an underlying `Encodable` instance. Although that being said, given the compiler magic already in place around the `Codable` API, I wouldn't be surprised if they made a special exception for `Encodable` conforming to `Encodable` in a future build (and hopefully this leads to a more general "any protocol with non-static requirements can conform to itself").