# Codable Protocol Conformance

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I want to implement a container type that conforms to `Codable`, but am running into a bit of an issue. I want to genericize my container to hold any element that can be Encodable & Decodable. Initially, I had this:

```
struct Container: Codable {
    var identifier: String
    var element: Any
}
```

...but changed it so that I could have some sort of type safety. Can someone explain what exactly is going on here?

**My Code**

```
struct Container: Codable {
    var identifier: String
    var element: Codable
}
```

**Compiler Output**

```
Playground execution failed:

MyPlayground.playground:3:9: note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') does not conform to 'Decodable'
    var element: Codable
...
```

Comment: Protocols don't conform to themselves, so `Codable` doesn't conform to `Codable`, therefore as not all properties of your type conform to `Codable`, you don't get an auto-generated conformance. Consider – what concrete type should Swift decode into for the `element` property?

Comment: Compare also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480667/jsonencoder-works-for-stringstring-fails-for-stringcodable